# Initializing riverpod Provider with a custom ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, state-management, riverpod, flutter-hooks

I'm just trying out the new [river_pod](https://riverpod.dev/), flutter state management library. My goal here is simple. `GestureDetector` in the main page listens to vertical drags and updates the animation controller accordingly. And I'd like to listen to this animation somewhere else. I have written the following code, and it's working as expected. But I don't feel like I'm initializing the provider in the right way.

```dart
// a custom notifier class
class AnimationNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final AnimationController _animationController;

  AnimationNotifier(this._animationController) {
    _animationController.addListener(_onAnimationControllerChanged);
  }

  void forward() => _animationController.forward();
  void reverse() => _animationController.reverse();

  void _onAnimationControllerChanged() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.removeListener(_onAnimationControllerChanged);
    super.dispose();
  }

  double get value => _animationController.value;
}

// provider variable, (not initialized here)
var animationProvider;

// main Widget
class GestureControlledAnimationDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GestureControlledAnimationDemoState createState() =>
      _GestureControlledAnimationDemoState();
}

class _GestureControlledAnimationDemoState
    extends State<GestureControlledAnimationDemo>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  double get maxHeight => 420.0;

   @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    // provider is initialized here
    animationProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((_) {
      return AnimationNotifier(_controller);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScaffold(
      title: 'GestureControlled',
      body: GestureDetector(
        onVerticalDragUpdate: _handleDragUpdate,
        onVerticalDragEnd: _handleDragEnd,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Yo',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                NotifierTest(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    _controller.value -= details.primaryDelta / maxHeight;
  }

  void _handleDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    if (_controller.isAnimating ||
        _controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed) return;

    final double flingVelocity =
        details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy / maxHeight;
    if (flingVelocity < 0.0) {
      _controller.fling(velocity: max(2.0, -flingVelocity));
    } else if (flingVelocity > 0.0) {
      _controller.fling(velocity: min(-2.0, -flingVelocity));
    } else {
      _controller.fling(velocity: _controller.value < 0.5 ? -2.0 : 2.0);
    }
  }
}

// Widget which uses the provider
class NotifierTest extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final animationNotifier = useProvider(animationProvider);
    double count = animationNotifier.value * 1000.0;
    return Container(
      child: Text(
        '${count.floor()}',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Since an animation controller instance is required to create an instance of `AnimationNotifier`, this can be done only after `_controller` initialization. So in the `initState()`, I've initialized both `_controller` and `animationProvider`. Is this the right way to use riverpod `Provider`?
If not, what modifications can be made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off I would highly recommend using hooks - it would reduce the boilerplate of your code significantly, for example, your class declaration will turn into:

```dart
class GestureControlledAnimationDemo extends HookWidget {
  double get maxHeight => 420.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _controller = useAnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    ...
  }
```

This removes the need for initState, dispose, etc.

Second, you don't necessarily want to create non-static providers inside classes. Instead, you could create it in global scope, or in this case, it makes sense to add as a static member on your custom notifier.

```dart
class AnimationNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  ...
  static final provider = ChangeNotifierProvider((_) {
    return AnimationNotifier(controller);
  });
}
```

But wait, we don't have any variable named `controller` in this scope, so how do we get access? We can create a provider for an AnimationController, or we can turn your provider into a [family](https://riverpod.dev/docs/fundamentals/concepts/family) so we can accept an AnimationController as a parameter. I will demonstrate the approach with families:

```dart
class AnimationNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  ...
  static final provider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose.family<AnimationNotifier, AnimationController>((_, AnimationController controller) {
    return AnimationNotifier(controller);
  });
}
```

I added autoDispose as you likely want your controllers disposed when they are no longer needed. Now, we use the provider:

```dart
class GestureControlledAnimationDemo extends HookWidget {
  double get maxHeight => 420.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = useAnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    final provider = useProvider(AnimationNotifier.provider(controller));
    ...
  }
```

If you do use hooks, make sure you change your riverpod dependency to [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod).

**EDIT:**

It looks like for your use case you could potentially store the current controller in a StateProvider, then read it from the ChangeNotifierProvider instead of using families.

```dart
final controllerProvider = StateProvider<AnimationController>((_) => null);

class AnimationNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  ...
  static final provider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose<AnimationNotifier>((ref) {
    final controller = ref.read(controllerProvider)?.state;
    return AnimationNotifier(controller);
  });
}
```

```dart
class GestureControlledAnimationDemo extends HookWidget {
  double get maxHeight => 420.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = useAnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 1));

    final currentController = useProvider(controllerProvider);
    currentController.state = controller;
    
    final notifier = useProvider(AnimationNotifier.provider);
    ...
  }
```

This should work. Note that when Riverpod 0.6.0 is released, you can also autodispose the StateProvider.

Comment: Thanks for this info. One doubt I have is, how do I use the provider with the same controller in another Widget? In the question code, at the end you can see a NotifierTest widget which uses the provider. If you could give a little more explanation on this one, it'd be really helpful.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed some of the code in your question. I will update my answer.